# Why for /D works in this case?

Tags: for-loop, cmd

Why this code works without any errors:

```
for /D %%i in (".exe";".cmd") do ( echo %%i )
```

But in help for command "for" written that command accept "Specifies a set of one or more files".

Comment: Because `command.com` was written by a group of drug-addled monkeys, and the only brief the `cmd.exe` team received was to maximise compatibility :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Clever, but `/D` wasn't a valid option before Windows 2000.

Answer (score 0):

In NT, for, dir, del, etc accept multiple filespecs.

```
del c:\folder\*.txt c:\folder\*.pdf
```

etc

or

```
 dir "%userprofile%\desktop\*.*" "%userprofile%\documents\*.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Microsoft documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx) on `for` command

```
for {%variable|%%variable} in (set) do command [ CommandLineOptions]
```

> **(set)** : Required. Specifies one or more files, directories, range of values, or text strings that you want to process with the specified
>   command
>
> **command** : Required. Specifies the command that you want to carry out on each file, directory, range of values, or text string included
>   in the specified (set).
>
> The for command replaces %variable or %%variable with each text string
>   in the specified set until the command processes all of the files
>
> **Specifying a group of files** 
>   The set parameter can represent a single group of files or several
>   groups of files. You can use wildcards (that is, * and ?) to specify a
>   file set
>
> When you use the for command, the first value in set replaces
>   %variable or %%variable, and then the specified command processes this
>   value. This continues until all of the files (or groups of files) that
>   correspond to the set value are processed

The documentation can be considered ambiguous: while it indicates that the `for` will iterate over files/folders, it does not state that the files/folders need to exist. Only when a wildcard is used the elements processed are real existing files/folders. But without a wildcard, no previous testing for element existence is done, the elements in the set are considered text strings.

`for` and `for /d` commands behave the same way (first one for files, second for directories):  iterate over the elements provided in the `in` clause, and, if any of them include wildcards, expand it and process the list of matching files/folders instead of the indicated element.

In your case,

```
for /D %%i in (".exe";".cmd") do ( echo %%i )
```

two elements are included to be processed (the `;` is considered a separator). So, the for iterates over the elements in this set. `".exe"` does not include wildcards, so, it needs no expansion and the `do` clause is executed for this element. Once done, the same process is repeated for `".cmd"`